# Set hotspot IP address

Tags: ubuntu, wifi-hotspot

I am trying to setup a WiFi hotspot on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything is working, and clients are able to connect to the hotspot.

How do I change the IP address that my hotspot is assigned? Right now, I am assigned `10.42.0.1` but say I want `192.168.0.1` instead.

I tried adding the following to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

But I am still assigned the same IP address.

Comment: You can change the `IP` of your hotspot by editing the hotspot config in settings and changing the `IPv4 Settings`.

Comment: The hotspot is likely created using `hostapd`, so look at the config files for `hostapd`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was adding the following line to my hotspot config file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myHotspot` in the *ipv4* block:

```
address1=192.168.0.1/24,192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Confirmed working on Kubuntu 16.04. Note after setting IP you need to restart network-manager using `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`.

Comment: You don't need the comma + IP, just specifying the CIDR works fine `address1=192.168.0.1/24` (as per [NetworkManager reference](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-keyfile.html))

Comment: this solution does not seem to work with 172.16.0.1/24 subnet, which is a valid private subnet..